# How to construct a non-trivial example that shows $A^{-1}A = I_X $ and $AA^{-1} = I_Y$, where $I_X \neq I_Y$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, operator-theory

Let $A: X \to Y$, and $A^{-1}:Y\to X$ be maps where $A^{-1}$ is the inverse of $A$

Then **$A^{-1}A =  I_X$** and **$AA^{-1} = I_Y$**

I can't think of good examples to demonstrate this result, because for $A$ a matrix (finite dimensional operator), there is no difference between $I_X$ and $I_X$, they are just the identity matrix of same dimension

How to construct an $A$ where $I_X \neq I_Y$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just take a bijective mapping between two different vector spaces of the same dimension. For instance, $X=\mathbb R^{m,n}$, $Y=\mathbb R^{n,m}$, $n\ne m$, and the mapping $A:X\to Y$ defined by
$$
A(M)=M^T.
$$